# How do you change selection color in the autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In Forge Viewer v3 we were setting the color of a selection like this:

```
onRequestClick(e) {
  const THREE_RED_COLOR = new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0);
  NOP_VIEWER.impl.setSelectionColor(THREE_RED_COLOR);
  NOP_VIEWER.select($(e.target).parent().find(`th`).data(`attributes`));
}
```

In v6, this code still selects the viewer objects as expected, but the selection color stays at default blue and does not change to red as expected.
Is this change done through a different method now? Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using viewer `viewer.clearSelection(); viewer.set2dSelectionColor(red)`

where `viewer=NOP_VIEWER; red = new THREE.Color(1,0,0)`

Does that fix it?

Comment: Hi Michale, is there any way to pass alpha channel into the selection colour?

Comment: What is NOP_VIEWER? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked fine when I tried with Viewer v6.4.2:

```
viewer.impl.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0));
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,()=>viewer.select(1))
```

See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/rLxypb6q/1/).

You might want to try relevant code again in your browser console to isolate the issue.

**EDIT**

If you look at the source it clearly states that it only works for the 3D models:

```
/**
     * Changes the color of the selection for 3D models.
     * 
     * @example
     *  viewer.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(0xFF0000)); // red color
     * @param {THREE.Color} color
     * 
     * @alias Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D#setSelectionColor
     */
    Viewer3D.prototype.setSelectionColor = function(color, selectionType) {
        this.impl.setSelectionColor(color, selectionType);
    };
```

Will log a feature request with Engineering to port this functionality to 2D models as well.

Comment: Your example is using the 3D viewer, is this code different using the 2D viewer? (sorry, forgot to mention in my original post that this is 2D) Also, I logged the function using the console and it looks like it takes in 2 parameters, not 1 ```ƒ (e,t){var n=new O.Color(e);n.multiplyScalar(.5);var i=function(t){t.color.set(e),t.emissive.set(n)};i(this.selectionMaterialBase),i(this.selectionMaterialTop),this.selectionMaterialBase.variants&&thi…
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confirming that it is not working on 2D files.
Here's a screenshot of my attempt.

I called the get Selection on the 2 circles. to confirm that the viewer was engaged and that I was able to detect different selection.

Then when I call the setSelectionColor function, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: for 2d sheet, the method to set selection color is: NOP_VIEWER.set2dSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(1,1,1))